# Custom URL Rewriting in core php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am working on URL rewriting in core PHP. I need help with it.

My URL has the following format:

```
http://xyz.in/index.php?view=wholesale&page=fcat&id=161
```

I want to convert it to:

```
http://xyz.in/ABC
```

Here `page` and `view` are parameters which are used for getting a particular page.

`ABC` is the category name whose category ID has the value `161` in the category table.

I found many solutions related to the `htaccess` file but they don't work for me because there is no solution where a value (category name) is retrieved from the database by using URL parameters (category ID).

Comment: Before you can event think about doing this rewrite, you need to update your code to be able to retrieve info by using the category name. mod_rewrite can't do this for you.

Comment: .htaccess file doesn't work in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add rewrite rule in .htaccess file like this,

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule index\.html index.php
Options -Indexes


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz\.in
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.xyz.in/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

#admin
//this is for single params
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/index.php$ ?page=ABC&category=$1 [L]

//If you need two params use this.
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/index.php$ ?page=ABC&category=$1&view=$2 [L]
```

You can get value from that particular page,

```
echo $_REQUEST['category'];
```

I hope you it will enough your solution.